# "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)") (HTTP 409)

Tags: openstack, devstack

I'm installing devstack using local rc file. After running the command `./stack.sh` my devstack installation is stuck at various places. Mostly error is the

> 2014-09-29 13:14:44.324 | Conflict occurred attempting to store role. (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)") (HTTP 409)

Comment: Looks like you're using the wrong password for MySQL? Perhaps you didn't set a password?

Comment: Are you sure you should be using `root` as the user?